# I can't see the option to create a group on my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook-groups

I created a Facebook page as a non-profit. I would like to add a private group. I don't seem to see an option to create a group anywhere. How do I create a group?

The Facebook help indicates to use the option on the left side menu but my page has nothing on the left side menu. Here is the [page](https://www.facebook.com/KnittingWithoutBorders).

Answer (score 2):

Here's the direct link to the [Groups page](https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/groups). You will have to administer the group from your account, not as the page.

Comment: when I click on the Groups link Facebook re-directs me to my page. If I click on Settings I don't see any option to create a group. I looked everywhere and can't seem to find the option. :(

Comment: I'd like to do this as well, but add three groups under my page since an account cannot be listed as a business. Because of that I converted my account to a page, but now there's no way to add groups to a page? That's very confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was that by default the Groups link in the menu was turned off.

I had to go to Settings > Templates and Tabs and change what was showing up.

There is a Nonprofit template, and by default it doesn't show Groups. I assume that was applied to your page when you selected something else during set up.

On that page you can see a list of Tabs and turn Groups on. Then when looking at your group you'll have Groups in the menu and you'll be able to create your link.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot create a new group, this is what I get:

This content isn't available right now
When this happens, it's usually because the owner only shared it with a small group of people, changed who can see it or it's been deleted.

Comment: I got the same issue like you. Can you now create a new group?